# How to stub the below senario using mocha chai sinon

Tags: unit-testing, google-cloud-functions, sinon, sinon-chai

I want to stub the mock response for below code how can i do that ?

```js
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";
const storage = new Storage();
import a from "./a.js"

export function abc(req, res) {
  a().then(result ->{
  const bucketName = result.bucketName;
  const fileName = "Sample.json";
  const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(result.fileName);
  const myfile = file.createReadStream();
  let buffer = "";
  myfile
    .on("data", function(a) {
      buffer += a;
    })
    .on("end", function() {
      console.log(buffer);
      res.status(200).send(buffer);
    });
    });
}
```

import a from "./a.js" is async function and i need to use mocha chai to write unit testing.

Comment: Are you exporting  correctly the modules in a.js? Have a look iinto this [tutorial](https://nodesource.com/blog/es-modules-and-node-js-hard-choices/). Let me know if works for you. Otherwise, I can look further to help you.

Comment: Yes , function const a= async () => { //logic  return result }
module.exports = a;

Answer (score 0):

Follow the next steps in order to export and import in Nodejs:

a.js

```
const a= async () => { 
//logic 
   return result 
}
module.exports = { a: a };
```

Cloud Function

```
const func = require('./a.js');
//Use the function like following: 
func.a()
```

Comment: Hi @Nibrass , I have tried as shown above and stubbed result but i got below error    TypeError: a.a(...).then is not a function  --- way i have stubbed sinon.stub(a, "a").callsFake(() => {
      return {
           resultStub
      };
  });

Comment: @Tapas Vishal, Could you update the post with the whole code? Do you think that the issue is in the way sinon library works?

Comment: Woking of sinon i know , But problem is how to mock a().then(result =>{}) result which i will get from a function

Comment: Do you did it in the following way,
func.a().then(result =>{}) ?

Comment: yes , Hi @slideshowp2 can you please help me with above case